# Wordpress inclusion in CodeIgniter leads to destroyed sessions

Tags: wordpress, codeigniter-2, session-cookies

I had to add a WordPress installation to my CodeIgniter system, so I've put it in a submap called `blog` and excepted that folder in my `.htaccess`. All good and well.

I've put the all WordPress tables together with in my CodeIgniter databases with prefix `_wp`.

I've now loaded the WordPress blog header file into the `index.php` of CodeIgniter, like so;

```
require('blog/wp-blog-header.php');
add_filter('site_url', 'ci_site_url', 1);

function ci_site_url() {
        include(FCPATH.'/application/config/config.php');
        return $config['base_url'];
}
```

And made a registration method in my `Account` controller to make an actual link to my `Customers`. I do this because I want to make the WordPress login/registration obsolete and solely control that from the CodeIgniter login page;

```
protected function register_wp($email_address = FALSE) {
    if ($email_address !== FALSE) {
        if (username_exists( $email_address ) == NULL) {
            $password = wp_generate_password(12, TRUE);
            $user_id = wp_create_user($email_address, $password, $email_address);
            wp_update_user(array(
                'ID' => $user_id,
                'nickname' => $email_address
            ));

            $user = new WP_User($user_id);
            $user->set_role('subscriber');

            $login_data = array(
                'user_id' => $user_id,
                'password' => $password,
            );

            return $login_data;
        }
        else {
            // User already exists with that email address
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
    else {
        // No email_address given
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

And the login method, to give an idea;

```
protected function login_wp($user_id = FALSE) {
    if ($user_id !== FALSE) {
        $user_login = 'admin';
        $user = get_userdatabylogin($user_login);
        $user_id = $user->ID;
        wp_set_current_user($user_id, $user_login);
        wp_set_auth_cookie($user_id);
        do_action('wp_login', $user_login);
    }
    else {
        // No user_id given
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

All still going well. But here comes the clash; something I was very sad about because everything worked very well up until now:

WordPress overtakes the session and kills CodeIgniter's session.

I already tried tons of things;

- `session_rename('PHPSESSIDWP');` and then starting another session (with another name) for CodeIgniter after WordPress was loaded
- COOKIE path (I'm not 100% sure if I done this right, as it didn't change at all. Read some things online it doesn't work well in all browsers either)
- COOKIE domain (seemed to have no effect)

The problem is I can't load the `require('blog/wp-blog-header.php');` only in the controller method, as I need to be able to control the logged in state of the WordPress part. Besides that I will get complaints about the `site_url()` function, that's already claimed by the URL helper.

I think the problem is mainly because both CodeIgniter and WordPress use their own unique way of handling Sessions (CI in the Database and WordPress in "super globals") which probably only makes them use the cookie to remember a "state".

My whole CodeIgniter system already runs on the Database-driven Session models so that's an absolute no-go to make a switch. For WordPress it seems it can't even work with session anymore with it's code features (I know session "do" work, but that doesn't seem to count in any way for the WP core system).

Also I quoted out `wp_unregister_GLOBALS();` in the `wp-settings.php` file.

Plus that I also tried to rename my session COOKIE name in CodeIgniter to use something like `session_ci`

I really hope someone knows a way to being able to tell CodeIgniter or WordPress to only update their values and don't kill the whole session each time. I also read something about splitting up cookies with `.htaccess` but can't find good resources on it. So if anyone knows how to do that, I would be eternally grateful.

I'm in despair. Finishing it for 98% and then getting such a letdown in the end :(..

***Update***

Maybe I can do something in the WordPress section that handles the cookies?

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_auth_cookie

Sadly I'm not really home in the WordPress world. I solely have to use it this one time due to the bought template that the people really wanted to use in the blog.

Also [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Cookies) page states the following;

*WordPress uses the two cookies to bypass the password entry portion of wp-login.php. If WordPress recognizes that you have valid, non-expired cookies, you go directly to the WordPress Administration interface. If you don't have the cookies, or they're expired, **or in some other way invalid** (like you edited them manually for some reason), WordPress will require you to log in again, in order to obtain new cookies.*

I wonder tho, how to bypass that "invalid" check, which probably is the reason it kills the CodeIgniter cookie(s)? Weirdly enough tho, it seems the `session_ci` value stays, although the session still seems killed.

Comment: Are you testing this locally? If yes then send me your project folder zipped (can get my email from profile).
I will play around and will see if I can help you with this.
Follow these,
http://planetozh.com/blog/2009/08/how-to-make-http-requests-with-wordpress/ (Preffered)

http://lud.icro.us/wordpress-http-api-basicauth

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/easy-authentication-with-codeigniter/

http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/58906/create-api-for-single-sign-on-with-3rd-party-site

https://bitbucket.org/osferanet/ciwp-auth/wiki/Home

Hope these helps, otherwise contact me.

Comment: Try this approach if possible,

[Session Manager](https://github.com/ericmann/wp-session-manager)

Comment: Did you find anything that works?

Comment: I had to round this up last year for a client. In the end I've just put WordPress in a subfolder (.htaccess routing) next to my CodeIgniter installation and linked them through a secret key with 2-way encryption and added a file in the WordPress that hooked in some WordPress core functions so I could link the registration, login and adjustment calls straight from my CodeIgniter CMS. So I pulled them apart fully and just added an extra field in my CodeIgniter CMS that indicated which WordPress User_ID that CMS user had linked. Not pretty, but was safe and worked like a charm. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

**You need to put your session start at the very top of config.php**. 
This is the only place a session will not be destroyed by WordPress.

```
if (!session_id())
session_start();
```

> If your PHP installation does not have register_global enabled, the
>   above code should allow you to use session, however, if it does, you
>   will not be able to get the data that was set in previous request.
>   This is because WordPress will destroy all data contained inside
>   session variable when it does the initialization.

Here's why and troubleshooting on this -> [kanasolution.com](http://www.kanasolution.com/2011/01/session-variable-in-wordpress/)

**EXPANDED ANSWERS:**

Source: http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Cookies

> On login, wordpress uses the wordpress_[hash] cookie to store your
>   authentication details. Its use is limited to the admin console area,
>   /wp-admin/
>
> After login, wordpress sets the wordpress_logged_in_[hash] cookie, which indicates when you're logged in, and who you are, for
>   most interface use.

So WordPress clearly dislikes the way that you're writing cookies, maybe their lack of 8 pass MD5 hash etc? [WordPress encryption methods](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_hash_password)

**The WordPress Environment**

The next thing I would try is integrating your custom login page into the WordPress environment instead of just requiring the header. (lets stay away from editing core)

From WordPress & AJAX by Ronald Huereca page 78 explains manually loading the WordPress environment.

The use of the dirname functions depend on the hierarchy of your file. Adjust them as needed. Code should be used before the  tag of your file.

```
$root = dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)))));
if (file_exists($root.'/wp-load.php')) {
require_once($root.'/wp-load.php'); 
/*Run custom WordPress stuff here */ 
//Output header HTML, queue scripts and styles, and include BODY content 
    wp_enqueue_script('my_script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/my_script.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0'); 
    wp_print_scripts(array('my_script'));
}
```

Comment: Sadly them problem isn't the session anymore at the point my situation is. It's about WordPress destroying the cookie, as it seems to think it's *unsafe*. Keeping a `$_SESSION` in-tact is not issue at this point. Yet both systems don't use native sessions.